# PHP: why i am getting this error ??? "syntax error, unexpected '{'"

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement

i wanted to arrange this arrays element in assending order and wrote the below code :

```
<?php 
  $a=array("z","s","a","j","t","b");
  for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++)
  {
  if ($i[0]<$i[1]) { echo $i[1]; }
  else if ($i[1]<$i[2]) { echo $i[2]; }
  else if ($i[2]<$i[3]) { echo $i[3]; }
  else if ($i[3]<$i[4]) { echo $i[4]; }
  else if ($i[4]<$i[5]) { echo $i[5]; }
  else if ($i[5]<$i[6]) { echo $i[6]; }
  else if ($i[6]<$i[7]) { echo $i[7]; }
  else if ($i[7]<$i[8]) { echo $i[8]; }
  else if ($i[8]<$i[9]) { echo $i[9]; }
  else if ($i[9]<$i[10]) { echo $i[10]; }
  else if ($i[10]<$i[11]) { echo $i[11]; }
  else ($i[11]<$i[12]) { echo $i[12]; }

 }

?>
```

but i an getting the following error :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\arange.php on line 16

how can i rectify it

Answer (score 7):

This snippet is the problem:

```
else ($i[11]<$i[12]) { echo $i[12]; }
```

Either edit it into `elseif` or remove the `($i[11]<$i[12])`.

Comment: +1 Good catch, it is invisible at first glance! @ravi: or write less code and make fewer mistakes ;)

Comment: Yes, had to look at it quite closely. :) @ravi, neither do I, but the error is gone. You really should look at PHP's `sort` function, as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: The problem is on a deeper level. You are handling the integer $i as if it was an array. I'm not even sure if your basic idea is correct but try replacing all $i in the loop with $a. It is still a non generic solution though. What happens when the array is larger than 13 elements?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this differently. Consider using PHP's built in [sort()](http://www.php.net/sort) function.

```
$a = array("z","s","a","j","t","b");
sort($a);
foreach ($a as $element) {
    echo "$element\n";
}
```

Also read about the [foreach statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = '';
$a=array("z","s","a","j","t","b");
foreach($a as $i) if($i > $b) $b = $i;
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the manual for a clear example of the [elseif/else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) syntax. The else part in your code is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($i[5]<$i[6]) { echo $i[6]; }
```

actually will output something like this;

```
if ( b < ) { echo ; }
```

That why you see kinda error...